# What are some pointers for newcomers?

Tags: maintenance, diy

Tldr: I'd like to know if there's any way for me to solve all of my problems on my own.
Good day there, I'm new to this community, and I'm very excited to join! I'd like to learn at least the fundamentals of cycling and cycles, as well as how to repair bikes, find parts, and get cheap bikes and parts, as well as how to ride properly. I was inspired to post here as I've been riding cycles since 6th grade (I'm in my 10th now) and I have somewhat more experience than most of my friends. However, there were so many things on this community's front page that I couldn't understand! I've always wondered if there was a way to fix my bike myself instead of letting cycle shops take advantage of me. But I'm not very good with hardware, and I'm afraid it'll break. I'm still learning the ins and outs of the cycle. I have a sunpeed zero, which is a bit less well known, but is a sibling company of Upten, Java, etc. Furthermore, I paid $200 for it. It comes with 21 gears and 29-inch wheels. It has Shimano Tourney gear (despite the fact that there are far too many with the same name) and Bolids brakes. However, after purchasing the cycle a year ago, I noticed that the springs were not working at all in the second week of ownership. It doesn't go down to how much you push. It will only go down if you push hard enough. I didn't want to repair it because I thought it was something I did, so it remained that way for a year. In addition, I've gone through three gear cycles in my life, all of which were plagued by bad gear systems (?). My previous one made a lot of noises while riding, especially when changing gears, and it didn't always change at all. Additionally, this occurred within the last two months of the current cycle. The front sprocket was apparently broken when I had it diagnosed and repaired. He replaced it for a fee of $25 USD. It didn't have a name. I'd like to know if there's a way for me to solve all of my problems on my own.

Comment: Welcome - start by reading the [tour]  This question is probably too broad and contains too many separate questions.  Also, many of them have been asked before, so do some searching for pre-existing questions, there's thousands of useful things already here.

Comment: You haver two broad questions in all this - how to get better at riding, and how to fix bikes. Both these have been covered in previous questions. Best options are a local bicycle club or bike coop (Bike repair facility manned by volunteers) if you have any. Failing the if you have a local 'Manz shed'  (place mostly older blokes go to hang out) could be worth a visit - usually someone with a career on the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill look into it. Local bike shop isn't an option as in my area everyone overcharges 2-4x the price...

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com Some of the stuff may be a bit dated, but maintenance, basic to the involved, is covered.  I suggest this site because it really kick started my holistic understanding of the bicycle. Working on bikes much of my life, I was good with some aspects (derailleurs and brakes), and just dumbfounded with other parts (bearing systems and frame aspects).  From the knowledge base of Sheldon Brown, I could go to other sources with a good understanding of what I was seeing. I now am quite average with most any aspect of bike maintenance. I try, though